# In nss ldap is it possible to change the default passwd access filter?

Tags: users, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to bend a QNAP device to my will and not quite getting there.

This seems like it should be simple but can't get it to work.

The device is linked to an Open Directory (OSX ldap v3) and authenticated to it to allow shares access; it uses nss ldap to link to it.

The default ldap search filter seems to be `(&(objectClass=posixAccount) (uid=*))` which isn't exactly what I would like.

Is there a way to change the nss ldap default filter to `(&(objectClass=posixAccount) (cn=*))`?

(the device is a TVS-871T if that makes any difference, running open ldap as far as I can tell)